# mad_libs personal learning project - issue updating text with user input

Tags: python, function, input, import

I am using Python to create a mad-libs style project - I am taking input of different verbs, nouns, and adjectives, and inputing them into the text placeholders. There seems to be a bug in my code - I am assuming it is within the save_crazy_lib function but I cant figure out where it is wrong. It may be elsewhere though.

Here is the terminal commands I am inputing -

```
michaelsmacbook@Michaelss-MBP Desktop % python3 crazy.py lib.txt 
Enter a VERB_ING:drink    
Enter a NOUN:water 
Enter a VERB_ING:go 
Enter a ADJECTIVE:quickly 
Enter a NOUN:north 
Enter a VERB_ING:smiling
Enter a NOUN:goth


michaelsmacbook@Michaelss-MBP Desktop % cat lib.txt
```

> The first thing that stands between you  and VERB_ING your first,
> real, piece of NOUN,  is VERB_ING the skill of breaking  problems down
> into achievable ADJECTIVE  actions that a NOUN can do for you. Of
> course, you and the computer will also  need to be VERB_ING a common
> NOUN, but  we'll get to that topic in just a bit.

Here is the mad libs program -

```
import sys


def make_crazy_lib(filename):
    try: 
        file = open(filename, 'r')
        text = ''

        for line in file:
            text = text + process_line(line)
        file.close()

        return text
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Sorry, cound't find" + filename + '.')
    except IsADirectoryError:
        print("Sorry", filename, 'is a directory.')
    except:
        print("Sorry, could not read", filename)

placeholders = ['NOUN', 'ADJECTIVE', 'VERB_ING','VERB']

def process_line(line):
    global placeholders
    processed_line = ''

    words = line.split()

    for word in words:
        stripped = word.strip('.,:?!')
        if stripped in placeholders:
            answer = input('Enter a ' + stripped + ":")
            processed_line = processed_line + answer 
            if word[-1] in '.,;?!':
                processed_line = processed_line + word[-1] + ' '
            else:
                processed_line = processed_line + ' ' 
        else:
            processed_line = processed_line + word + ' ' 

    return processed_line + '\n'

def save_crazy_lib(filename, text): #This may be where the issue is
    try:
        file = open(filename, "w")
        file.write(text)
        file.close()
    except:
        print("Sorry, couldn't write file." + filename, lib)


def main():
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print("crazy.py<filename>")
    else:
        filename = sys.argv[1]
        lib = make_crazy_lib(filename)
        if (lib != None):
            save_crazy_lib('crazy' + filename, lib)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I expected the placeholders to update to the input values when the module was run.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have your input file, so I can't try to reproduce your exact problem.  I can, however, tell you that the core logic of your code, the `process_line` function, seems to do what you are expecting.

I took your code and reduced it down to something that will run without the need for an external data file.  That code is below. Note that I did not change the `process_line` function at all.  When I run this code, I think I get the result that you want.  I supply the results of my execution below as well.

Code:

```
data = """
The first thing that stands between you  and VERB_ING your first,
real, piece of NOUN,  is VERB_ING the skill of breaking  problems down
into achievable ADJECTIVE  actions that a NOUN can do for you. Of 
course, you and the computer will also  need to be VERB_ING a common
NOUN, but  we'll get to that topic in just a bit.
"""

def make_crazy_lib():
    text = ''
    for line in data.splitlines():
        text = text + process_line(line)
    return text

placeholders = ['NOUN', 'ADJECTIVE', 'VERB_ING','VERB']

def process_line(line):
    global placeholders
    processed_line = ''

    words = line.split()

    for word in words:
        stripped = word.strip('.,:?!')
        if stripped in placeholders:
            answer = input('Enter a ' + stripped + ":")
            processed_line = processed_line + answer 
            if word[-1] in '.,;?!':
                processed_line = processed_line + word[-1] + ' '
            else:
                processed_line = processed_line + ' ' 
        else:
            processed_line = processed_line + word + ' ' 

    return processed_line + '\n'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lib = make_crazy_lib()
    print(lib)
```

Result:

```
Enter a VERB_ING:VI1
Enter a NOUN:N1
Enter a VERB_ING:VI2
Enter a ADJECTIVE:A1
Enter a NOUN:N2
Enter a VERB_ING:VI3
Enter a NOUN:N3

The first thing that stands between you and VI1 your first, 
real, piece of N1, is VI2 the skill of breaking problems down 
into achievable A1 actions that a N2 can do for you. Of 
course, you and the computer will also need to be VI3 a common 
N3, but we'll get to that topic in just a bit.
```

I can't think why your code would not be working.  I hope that you can confirm that the code I give here works for you as well, and then you can work between this version and your own version to figure out what is different between the two that causes one version to work and the other to misbehave.  I wonder if it has something to do with EOL characters or character encoding.

Have you run your code in a debugger and checked what it is doing?  Is the code matching any of the `placeholders`?  It seems that it can't be since you would have to be getting different output if it were.  So the key question is why the line:

```
if stripped in placeholders:
```

is always failing.  Place a breakpoint on that line and you should be able to confirm this by seeing that your code never ventures into the `if` block.  Then, by looking at `stripped` and `placeholders`, you should be able to tell why this comparison always fails.

BTW, you don't need the line `global placeholders`.  You would only need this if you were assigning a value to `placeholders` inside the containing function.